# List divider text is not being updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am building an Ionic app which has a list that is split using '**item divider**'

The problem i am having is that when I use the buttons I have in the app to change the list order etc the divider text is not changing.

The divider text items are generated within an Angular directive.

I feel as though the problem is that the directive is not being re-called when the button is clicked.

Below is the code for the list and the directive.

I have also created a codepen to play about with if that makes things any easier.

**Here is the [CODEPEN LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rrdgvd?editors=1010)**

***Notice that when you use the search bar then delete the word the list does update***

> HTML/Ionic markup for the list

```
<ion-list id="list">
  <ion-item 
            auto-list-divider 
            auto-list-divider-value="{{item[dividerString]}}" 
            auto-list-divider-function="dividerFunction" 
            ng-click="setDataSetClick(item.marker)" 
            ng-href="#/tab/films/{{item.id}}" 
            ng-repeat="item in outputData | filter:search.string | orderBy:dividerString:true">
    <!-- If Film data show title p -->
    <h3 ng-if="item.marker=='film';">{{item.title}}</h3>
    <!-- If Cinema data show title p -->
    <h3 ng-if="item.marker=='cinema';">{{item.cinema}}</h3>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

> Angular Controller

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicScrollDelegate, Films, Cinemas, FilterList, OrderList, DataSetString, $ionicActionSheet) {
  'use strict';
  var cachedFilmData = Films.all(),
    cachedCinemaData = Cinemas.all(),
    indexedFilms = [];

  $scope.dividerFunction = function(key) {
    return key;
  };

  $scope.search = {
    string: ''
  };
  $scope.dividerString = "year";
  $scope.outputData = cachedFilmData;
  $scope.filterString = FilterList.getFilter();
  $scope.orderString = OrderList.getOrder();

  $scope.itemsToFilter = function() {
    indexedFilms = [];
    return $scope.outputData;
  };

  $scope.filterFilms = function(films) {
    var uniqueFilm = indexedFilms.indexOf(films[$scope.dividerString]) === -1;
    if (uniqueFilm) {
      indexedFilms.push(films[$scope.dividerString]);
    }
    return uniqueFilm;
  };

  $scope.setDataSetClick = function(data) {
    DataSetString.setString(data);
  };

  // When the filter by button is clicked
  $scope.showFilterActionSheet = function() {
    $ionicActionSheet.show({
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Film'
      }, {
        text: 'Cinema'
      }],
      titleText: 'Select A Filter',
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      buttonClicked: function(index, obj) {
        FilterList.setFilter(obj.text);
        $scope.filterString = FilterList.getFilter();
        if ($scope.filterString === "Cinema") {
          $scope.outputData = cachedCinemaData;
          $scope.dividerString = "opened";
          DataSetString.setString('cinema');
        } else {
          $scope.outputData = cachedFilmData;
          $scope.dividerString = "year";
          DataSetString.setString('film');
        }
        // Reset the order string tex
        $scope.orderString = "Date";
        return true;
      }
    });
  };

  // When the order by button is clicked
  $scope.showOrderActionSheet = function() {
    var activeDataSet = DataSetString.getString();
    var optOne, optTwo, optThree;
    if (activeDataSet === "cinema") {
      optOne = "Opened";
      optTwo = "Closed";
      optThree = "Highlights";
    } else {
      optOne = 'Date';
      optTwo = 'Themes';
      optThree = 'Highlights';
    }
    $ionicActionSheet.show({
      buttons: [{
        text: optOne
      }, {
        text: optTwo
      }, {
        text: optThree
      }],
      titleText: 'Select An Order',
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      buttonClicked: function(index, obj) {
        var orderText = obj.text,
          divider;
        if (activeDataSet === "cinema") {
          if (orderText === "Opened") {
            divider = "opened";
          }
          if (orderText === "Closed") {
            divider = "closed";
          }
          if (orderText === "Highlights") {
            divider = "highlight";
          }
          sortData(cachedCinemaData, divider);
        } else {
          if (orderText === "Date") {
            divider = "year";
          }
          if (orderText === "Themes") {
            divider = "theme";
          }
          if (orderText === "Highlights") {
            divider = "highlight";
          }
          sortData(cachedFilmData, divider);
        }
        $scope.orderString = obj.text;
        $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop(true);
        return true;
      }
    });
  };

  function sortData(data, divider) {
    $scope.outputData = [];
    var newOutputData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      if (data[i][divider] != 0) {
        console.log(divider);
        newOutputData.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
    $scope.outputData = newOutputData;
    $scope.dividerString = divider;
  }
})
```

> Angular Directive

```
.directive('autoListDivider', function($timeout) {
  var lastDivideKey = "";
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var key = attrs.autoListDividerValue,
        doDivide;

      doDivide = function() {
        var divideFunction = scope.$apply(attrs.autoListDividerFunction),
          divideKey = divideFunction(key);
        if (divideKey !== lastDivideKey) {
          element.prepend(
            '<h2 class="item item-divider custom--item-divider"><span ng-bind="divideKey">' + divideKey + '</span></h2>'
          )
        }
        lastDivideKey = divideKey;
      };

      $timeout(doDivide, 0);
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Everything works to me in CODEPEN provided. Could you please elaborate more what's not working?

Comment: It does not work as it should. The divider text is not updating. It should change the text from date format to string when ordering. For example if you change the order from date to highlight the item divider text should be the string that is in the data